# Can't update nor create data using Entity Framework Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Edit: Got past the issue in the PUT (was a null value going into a non-null field), but still having issues with the POST

I'm trying to setup a simple generic repository in my project using EF Core 2. The Gets and the Updates work fine but I'm having issues with the Create. Specifically, the value received at HttpPost in the controller is null. What is weird is that the HttpPut works fine in the controller and the Company is received with all its data.

Here is my generic repo class:

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IGenericRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    protected DriverDbContext _dbContext;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DriverDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetAll()
    {
        return await _dbSet.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(long id)
    {
        return await _dbSet
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        // entity has good data but SavaChangesAsync does nothing
        _dbSet.Update(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task Delete(long id)
    {
        var entity = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

Here is my controller:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Company")]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{

    private ICompanyRepository _repository;

    public CompanyController(ICompanyRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompanies()
    {
        return Json(await _repository.GetAll());
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompany(int id)
    {
        var company = await _repository.GetById(id);

        if (company == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Json(company);
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany([FromBody]CompanyViewModel company)
    {
        if (company == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        var newCompany = Mapper.Map<Company>(company);

        await _repository.Create(newCompany);

        return Created($"/api/company/{company.Name}", Mapper.Map<CompanyViewModel>(newCompany));

    }

    [HttpPut()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCompany([FromBody]CompanyViewModel company)
    {
        if (company==null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        if (_repository.GetById(company.Id) == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var updatedCompany = Mapper.Map<Company>(company);
        await _repository.Update(updatedCompany);
        return new NoContentResult();
    }
}
```

Here is the company entity:

```
public class Company : IEntity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Blacklisted { get; set; }
    public string BlacklistedComments { get; set; }
    public string BrokerAgreementStatus { get; set; }
    public float CompanyInvoiceDiscount { get; set; }
    public float PassThroughFee { get; set; }
    public int StandardHoursBilled { get; set; }
    public float StandardGM { get; set; }
    public float StandardMarkupFromBase { get; set; }
    public float StandardMarkupFromLoaded { get; set; }
    public float StandardEquipmentCost { get; set; }
    public long LastEditByUserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastEditDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the company view model:

```
public class CompanyViewModel
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Blacklisted { get; set; }
    public string BlacklistedComments { get; set; }
    public string BrokerAgreementStatus { get; set; }
    public float CompanyInvoiceDiscount { get; set; }
    public float PassThroughFee { get; set; }
    public int StandardHoursBilled { get; set; }
    public float StandardGM { get; set; }
    public float StandardMarkupFromBase { get; set; }
    public float StandardMarkupFromLoaded { get; set; }
    public float StandardEquipmentCost { get; set; }
    public long LastEditByUserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my angular company service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Company } from './company';
import { MessageService } from '../message/message.service';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class CompanyService {

    private baseUrl = 'api/company';

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient,
        private messageService: MessageService) {
    }

    private log(message: string) {
        this.messageService.add('CompanyService: ' + message);
    }

    getCompanies(): Observable<Company[]> {
        return this.http.get<Company[]>(this.baseUrl)
            .pipe(
                tap(companies => this.log(`fetched companies`)),
                catchError(this.handleError('getCompanies', []))
                );
    }

    //Handle Http operation that failed.
    //Let the app continue.
    //@param operation - name of the operation that failed
    //@param result - optional value to return as the observable result

    getCompany(id: number): Observable<Company> {
        if (id === 0) {
            return Observable.of(this.initializeCompany());
        }
        return this.http.get<Company>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`).pipe(
            tap(_ => this.log(`fetched Company id=${id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Company>(`getCompany id=${id}`))
        );
        }

    initializeCompany(): Company {
        return {
            id: 0,
            name: null,
            address: null,
            city: null,
            state: null,
        };
    }

    saveCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
        if (company.id === null) {
            return this.addCompany(company);
        }
        return this.updateCompany(company);
    }

    updateCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
        return this.http.put<Company>(this.baseUrl, company, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap((company: Company) => this.log(`updated company id=${company.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('updateCompany'))
        );
    }

    addCompany(company: Company): Observable<Company> {
        return this.http.post<Company>(this.baseUrl, company, httpOptions).pipe(
            tap((company: Company) => this.log(`added company id=${company.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<any>('addCompany'))
        );
    }

    private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
        return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

            // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
            console.error(error); // log to console instead

            // TODO: better job of transforming error for user consumption
            //this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

            // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
            return of(result as T);
        };
    }


}
```

Here is the startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    private IConfiguration _config;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<DriverDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("DriverDBConnection")));

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddScoped<ICompanyRepository, CompanyRespository>();


    } 

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<CompanyViewModel, Company>().ReverseMap();
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
}
```

The CompanyRespository is an empty child class of the GenericRepository

Here is the request payload to the Post:

```
{"id":null,
"name":"Some Company",
"address":null,
"city":null,
"state":"",
"zipcode":null,
"phone":null,
"email":null,
"comments":null,
"type":null,
"blacklisted":false,
"blacklistedComments":null,
"brokerAgreementStatus":"N/A",
"companyInvoiceDiscount":0,
"passThroughFee":0,
"standardHoursBilled":0,
"standardGM":0,
"standardMarkupFromBase":0,
"standardMarkupFromLoaded":0,
"standardEquipmentCost":0,
"lastEditByUserID":0,
"lastEditDate":"2018-01-10T23:03:05.303Z"}
```

Here is the Request Header

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:447
Content-Type:application/json
Host:localhost:56241
Origin:http://localhost:56241
Referer:http://localhost:56241/companies/0/edit
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: My man, if you want help you need to add listings for your `Company`, `CompanyViewModel`, `CompanyRepository` and captured HTTP requests to your `Create` and `Update`.

Comment: @zaitsman Yeah, sorry. I added that. The model and view model are identical for now. I also added the code for the angular service. I just noticed that the server is returning back a 500 error on the Put. It is also returning back a 400 on the Post due to the entity being null.

Comment: Can you capture your http `REQUEST` and add it?

Comment: @zaitsman Well, I was about to then figured i'd make the async update synchronous to see if I would get a real error message and I did. The issue was a null value in a non-null field. That fixed it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you show your startup code?

Comment: @Zaitsman I've gotten past the Put issue but still having a null value in the controller in the Post handler. I've edited the question to note that. Also included startup.cs

Comment: @H.Herzi I've included the startup.cs

Comment: @Alex if your viewmodel is null that is most likely because json you're posting doesn't match the model binding you have. e.g. `id` is `null` in the post, but is declared as `long` in the ViewModel. That won't bind, make it `long?` or post 0. Or omit it from the request.

Comment: @H.Herzi. Thank you, that was it. The Id field was null in the object going into the HttpPost handler. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task Create(TEntity entity)
{
    _dbSet.Add(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task Update(TEntity entity)
{
    // entity has good data but SavaChangesAsync does nothing
    _dbSet.Update(entity);
    _dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

public async Task Delete(long id)
{
    var entity = await _dbSet.FindAsync(id);
    if (_dbContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached)
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
    _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Don't just blurt out code. Please add an explanation how this best answers the question the OP asked.